# Modify hovertemplate in plotly line chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the shiny app below in which I want to modify the `hovertemplate` in a way that it will display `Name`, `Week` and `lab`(value in more aesthetic form). The issue is that I have already used `customdata` to display `lab` and I do not know how could I display `Name`.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
full_data<-data.frame("Name"=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q3"),"Values"=c(245645,866556,26440,65046,641131,463265),
                      "Week"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))
desc <- full_data %>% 
  group_by(Name,Week) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(Values)) %>%
  mutate(lab = scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(values))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    plotlyOutput("pl")
  )
  ,
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$pl<-renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(desc,
              x = ~Week, 
              y = ~values,
              #text = ~values,
              color = ~Name,
              colors = c("#60ab3d","#6bbabf","#c4d436","#3e5b84","#028c75","red"),
              customdata = mapply(function(x,y) list(x,y), desc$lab, desc$Name, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)) %>%
        add_trace(
          type = 'scatter',
          mode = 'lines+markers',
          hovertemplate = paste(
            "%{x}",
            "%{customdata[0]}", 
            "%{customdata[1]}", 
            "<extra></extra>",
            sep = "\n"),
          hoveron = 'points')
      
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
customdata = mapply(function(x,y) list(x,y), desc$lab, desc$Name, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

and

```
hovertemplate = paste(
  "%{color}",
  "%{x}",
  "%{customdata[0]}", 
  "%{customdata[1]}", 
  "<extra></extra>",
  sep = "\n")
```

Comment: sorry I have edited a little bit my dataframe and it does not work now

Comment: @firmo23 Try `mapply(function(x,y) list(x,y), desc$lab, desc$Name, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)`.

Comment: I get same issue: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 2: Columns `x`, `y`, `color`, `hovertemplate`, `.plotlyGroupIndex`, and 2 more.
* Size 6: Column `customdata`.
[34mℹ[39m Only values of size one are recycled.

Comment: @firmo23 I think you misuse `dplyr`. I'm not familiar with this package. But I think you have to use `ungroup` when you use `group_by`.

Comment: the desc dataset is created normally. the issue is the mapply()

Comment: @firmo23 No. The error message says that `x` has only two elements. However it has six elements.

Comment: I dont get it. I can see that the dataset and customdata are created without problem. The problem is when they are combined with hovertemplate?

Comment: @firmo23 Your tibble is *grouped*. Do `%>% ungroup()` after `summarise`.

Comment: desc <- full_data %>% 
  group_by(Name,Week) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(Values)) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(lab = scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(values))       does not work.gives the same error later

Comment: I gave u that since it answers initial Q and created a new one since its urgent to find an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460232/grouping-dataframe-causes-error-when-it-is-combined-with-plotl-ly