# Pass more than one column to customdata in plotly when color is mapped

Tags: r, plotly

If I do not map any value to  `color` the following code works smoothly:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
d <- tibble(x = 1:10, 
            g = gl(2, 5), 
            y = sample(100, 10), 
            L = LETTERS[1:10], l = letters[1:10])

plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_bars(x = ~ x, y = ~ y, customdata = ~ map2(l, L, list),
           hovertemplate = "%{customdata[0]}:%{customdata[1]}")
```

[image: Plotly barchart with the hover information properly displayed as a:A]

However, when I try to give the bars a different color, the (internal) shape of the data changes and R is complaining about non matching shapes:

```r
plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_bars(x = ~ x, y = ~ y, color = ~ g, customdata = ~ map2(l, L, list),
           hovertemplate = "%{customdata[0]}:%{customdata[1]}")
```

> ```
> Error in `recycle_columns()`:
> ! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
> • Size 5: Columns `x`, `y`, `color`, `hovertemplate`, `.plotlyTraceIndex`, and
>   2 more.
> • Size 10: Column `customdata`.
> ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> ```

Obviously, my `customdata` is in the wrong shape, but I have no idea, how I need to pass it, such that plotly can work with it?

Comment: You can simply give a character string: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/67464609/1100107>.

Comment: Sure, this will always be a workaround, but I was genuinely intersted to learn how to pass n-dim data to `customdata`

Comment: I already encountered this problem. This workaround was the final solution.

Comment: By the way I think this should be reported as a bug (of **tiblle** or **plotly** I don't know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it more simply:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
d <- tibble(x = 1:10, 
            g = gl(2, 5), 
            y = sample(100, 10), 
            L = LETTERS[1:10], l = letters[1:10])

d <- tibble(x = 1:10, 
            g = gl(2, 5), 
            y = sample(100, 10), 
            L = LETTERS[1:10], l = letters[1:10])

plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_bars(x = ~ x, y = ~ y,  hovertext = ~g, marker = list(color = ~g), customdata = ~ map2(l, L, list),
           hovertemplate = "%{customdata[0]}:%{customdata[1]}(%{hovertext})<extra></extra>")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow so easy? Just mapping the color inside marker? I think this answer is almost perfect. Unless somebody comes with the proper way of how to  supply `customdata`  in the presence of `color = ~g`, I will ba happily awarding the bounty here.

Comment: I have edited my post to remove the trace ut I am not too sure on how to integrate the grouping in the hovertemplate.

Comment: I have now managed to include the group inside hovertemplate as : a:A(1)

Comment: This is nice! However, when I run this the plot doesn't look like your image (using `plotly v4.10.1`). The inclusion of `text = ~ g` overlays the group number on to each bar. You can remove it though by changing it to `hovertext = ~g` and `hovertemplate = "%{customdata[0]}:%{customdata[1]}<extra>%{hovertext}</extra>"`. Note I have put the group inside the `<extra>` tag so you get the same color scheme for the text and background as you would with the text which says `"trace0"`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @SamR. I have edited my code as it appears that I had v4.9.2 installed and I have now installed v4.10.2, so my actual code is now working with 4.10.2. I just edited text to hovertext. Thank you again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

I think this may be a bug in `plotly`. Your error tells you that columns `x` and `y` have are length `10` and `customdata` is length `5`. However, if you reshape the data so `customdata` is length `5`, e.g. by supplying `customdata = ~ split(map2(l, L, list), 1:5)`, you get the converse error:

```r
Error in `recycle_columns()`:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
• Size 5: Column `customdata`.
• Size 10: Columns `x`, `y`, and `color`.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
```

Supplying two lists, each of length `5`, e.g. with `customdata = ~ split(map2(l, L, list), g)` also produces an error.

Fortunately there is an alternative approach which actually has some advantages. We can create a function which adds each group as its own trace. This also means we do not have to specify `color` directly (though you can) as `plotly` uses distinct colors for each trace. It also creates a legend automatically.

```r
add_customdata_by <- function(d, x, y, by_col, custom_col1 = l, custom_col2 = L, fn = list) {
    d_split <- d |>
        mutate(customdata = map2({{ custom_col1 }}, {{ custom_col2 }}, fn)) |>
        split(d[[by_col]])

    Reduce(\(p, d) add_bars(
        p,
        x = ~x, y = ~y, customdata = ~ customdata,
        hovertemplate = "%{customdata[0]}:%{customdata[1]}",
        data = d,
        name = unique(d$g)
    ), d_split, init = plot_ly())
}
```

We can call this with:

```r
add_customdata_by(d, x, y, by_col = "g")
```

In this example case, this is the same as calling `plot_ly()` followed by two `add_bars()` calls, one for each level of `g`. However, this will generalise to any number of groups.

#### Output

[image]

I imagine the main purpose of your `customdata` may not be for `hoverinfo` (otherwise you could just add `text = ~sprintf("%s:%s", l, L), hoverinfo = "text"` to a single `add_bars()` call). However, if you are using it for hover text, this approach also has the advantage of replacing `"trace0"`, which each label is appended with by default, with the name of the group.

Comment: Great, love this workaround and if not other answer will arrive will be happy to award the bounts. However, out of curiosity I would really love to know how we are meant to pass n-dimensional data to `customdata` in the presence of a color aesthetic.

Comment: @thothal thanks. I've just edited to make it a bit more generalisable - you can now pass any two columns to `map2()`, as well as functions other than `list`. But yes, I also cannot work out a way that you could pass the data with just one call to `add_bar()`. Please do leave this open - if someone else knows how to do it you should certainly award them the bounty and I'll be pleased to have learned something.